# org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature is not defined in my rest API

Tags: java, api, jersey, glassfish

I have created a small REST API which seems to work just fine. I wanted to use the Twitter API and display some tweets. But when I try to do that my server throws an error.

Reaching one of my old resources works just fine when trying this URL: http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/api/v1/foo/bar:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String print2() {
        return "This should be printed if in foo/bar";
    }
```

But If I try my "twitter method" at http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/api/v1/foo/twitter:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/twitter")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String print5() {
        //I have my real tokens here of course.
        ClientIdentifier ci = new ClientIdentifier("clientID",
                "ClientSecret");

        OAuth2CodeGrantFlow flow = OAuth2ClientSupport
                .authorizationCodeGrantFlowBuilder(ci,
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token")
                .scope("contact")
                .build();

        String finalAuthorizationUri = flow.start();

        return "This is the bearer: " + finalAuthorizationUri.toString();
    }
```

It throws the following error:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature
```

In reality it should just print my bearer token. I have tried importing various jackson jar files but not managed to get it working. I might add that I use Tomcat v8 and not Glassfish server.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a jar, specifically jersey-media-json-jackson-2.XX.jar (where XX is the version of jersey that you are using)

you can add the maven dependency like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```